# How to get data form mysql databse within different dates?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have table called reservations.And I have following values.

```
res_id hotel_id room_type start      end        qty
  1048        1 standard  2015-05-18 2015-05-20   1
```

I have a hotel search option. And if user enter start date as **2015-05-16** and end date as **2015-05-19** and search my bookedrooms.php display zero value for standard room type. My sql query is;

```
$sql1 = mysql_query("select * from reservations where start >= '".$start."'
```

and

```
end <= '".$end."'   and  room_type = 'standard' ");
```

if there any error in my checking dates,

```
start >= '".$start."' and end <= '".$end."'
```

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: What does this have to do with javascript or jquery?

Comment: I want to get quantity of room type between two days?

Comment: Can you do a between on two fields?  he has a start and end date, no a available_date persay

Comment: There is a error when use between.

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Hotel_Reservation\select_rooms.php on.............

Comment: Wait, hold on a second... '2015-05-20' <= '2015-05-19'  That's not a true statement.  Of course your going to get zero...

Comment: Without the context of the business case I cannot say if this is a problem or if the answer is simply "It works as intended.  Use different data."  Your going to have to ask yourself if this is correct or if your conditional regarding "end" is correct or not.  If not, then you need to detail more exactly the case your trying to match against, and adjust the query to match.

Answer (score 0):

Are start and end actual dates?  If so you should probably cast them.

```
"select * from reservations where start >= date('".$start."') and end <= date('".$end."') and room_type = 'standard' "
```

Comment: Then please try what Airclo below asked.  Can you echo or error_log $start and $end to make sure they are the values you expected them to be?  And can you be more specific as to 'not working'?  Still returns 0 results?  Returns an sql exception?  What?

Comment: it gives the 0 value for standard room type between  2015-05-17 and 2005-05-19.

Comment: Did you mean 2015-05-19?

Comment: Yes i want to get qty of standard rooms in above date range.